# Is it okay to provide a signature in a confirmation box?

Tags: copywriting, messages, dialog, messagebox

I'm providing counseling on an enterprise IT solution that delivers Windows security updates the way they want, and the message they want to use feels off.

The system delivers a dialog box once updates are pushed to the computer and a restart a required.

The proposed copy for the box is as follows:

> Important security updates have been made to your computer.
>
> To complete these updates, please restart your computer as soon as possible.
>   ...
>
> [*Company name*] IT Helpdesk

There are a number of usability issues I'm working through on this, but I need guidance on the idea of providing a "signature" within a dialog box.

I feel "signing" the dialog box is wrong, because it's not the tone or content that the user expects in this context.

On one hand, identifying the source of the message should increase trust and engagement. On the other hand, I would find a message like this as suspicious and possibly malware, because of the unorthodox writing.

I can't find any guidance on this idea one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, if you're worrying about Authenticity, almost anyone can emulate the signature you have specified in the dialog box unless there is a unique code you have.

> A dialog box is a secondary window that prompts an exchange of
>   information between the user and the program.

As per the [Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb246466(v=vs.85).aspx) for Dialog Boxes:

**Do not use customized dialog boxes when standard dialog boxes exist.**

Adding a Signature to the dialog box will mean that you're customizing it in one way or the other and might actually look even more suspicious since the consistency is broken.

You could rather mention the upgrade version so someone can keep a track of it and also push Change logs online and have an option to view the Change logs through another button on the Dialog box: *View Changes*

> Security updates successful. System is now on **v2.4.5**. Please restart to apply.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the purposes of the signature are 1) *let the user know who's responsible* and 2) *reassure them that this message is legitimate*.

I would handle #1 by adding that information directly to the text, and #2 by explicitly telling them how to verify the message. Here's an example:

> [Company Name] IT has made important security updates to your computer.
>
> To complete the updates, please restart your computer as soon as possible.
>
> If you have questions, please contact us at [company IT email address / web portal].

Providing contact info offers some reassurance that you're not trying to hustle them.

---

This doesn't address the other challenge faced by this dialog box, which is that many users would rather [burst into flames](https://xkcd.com/1328/) than drop what they're doing and restart.